# Need help retrieving data from Mysql database using HTML and JSP

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

So I am trying to get data from MySQL database into a table in HTML. The database has movie info and has 5 columns with headers such as movieID, title, and so on. I have made my connection to the database and retrieved data, but I dont really know how to format the results to look like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctAjJ.png)

Instead my results look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoXuv.png)

Here is my code, any help is appreciated.

```
<%@ include file = "header.html" %>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.Statement" %>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.DriverManager" %>
<html>
<%
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String cxnString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alfonsom?user=root&password=bcis3680";
Connection cxn = DriverManager.getConnection(cxnString);
Statement stm = cxn.createStatement();
String sql ="select * from movie;";
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next()){ 
%>
<body>
<table border="2" cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
        <th> &nbsp </td>
        <th> Movie ID</td>
        <th> Title</td>
        <th> Genre</td>
        <th> MPAA Rating</td>
        <th> Release Date</td>
    </tr>

        <td><input type="radio" name="movie" value="10001">

        <td><%=rs.getString("mid") %></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("title") %></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("genre") %></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("mpaa") %></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("rlsdate") %></td>
        <% } %>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change where you perform the loop.

```
<%@ include file = "header.html" %>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.Statement" %>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.DriverManager" %>
<html>
<%
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String cxnString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alfonsom?user=root&password=bcis3680";
Connection cxn = DriverManager.getConnection(cxnString);
Statement stm = cxn.createStatement();
String sql ="select * from movie;";
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
%>
<body>
<table border="2" cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
        <th> &nbsp </td>
        <th> Movie ID</td>
        <th> Title</td>
        <th> Genre</td>
        <th> MPAA Rating</td>
        <th> Release Date</td>
    </tr>

<%
while(rs.next()){ 
%>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="movie" value="10001"></td>

        <td><%=rs.getString("mid") %></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("title") %></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("genre") %></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("mpaa") %></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("rlsdate") %></td>
    </tr>
        <% } %>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This removed repetition of my headers, but now all data is being displayed on one row.

Comment: Figured it out, had to put my while loop right before my radio button.

Comment: FYI, in your original code, you were missing the <tr> </tr> and one </td>